# Javascript function onclick

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, function

I am trying to call a jquery script that will post data to a PHP form.
Been googling this for 5h now but i cant seems to solve it on my own.
The Script looks like this.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
    function postscrape(igid, iguser, groupid) {

        alert(igid);
        $.post("scrapeadder.php", {
                instagramid: igid,
                username: iguser,
                groupid: groupid
            },
            function(data, status) {
                alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
            });
    };
</script>
```

And my HTML/PHP code to call this function looks like:

```
  echo '<td><button type="button" class="btn btn-success datascraper" name="addscrape" id="addscrape" onclick="postscrape('.$row["instagram_id"].', '.$row["user_name"].', 1);">Add to Scrape</button></td>';
```

The error i get is: `Uncaught ReferenceError: X is not defined`

Where X = The iguser (which gets from $row["user_name"]
If i check the HTML code on the homepage it list all the $rows correct. So my guess is i messed up in the function.

Comment: Maybe you should post the code that contains the error instead ?

Comment: I second that request

Comment: are you able to print out the $row["instagram_id"].', '.$row["user_name"] and sure that there valid

Comment: Yes, when i check the source code in my webbrowser i can see the correct values in all those variables.

Comment: Always look at the clientside code generated by the serverside. Do not debug from looking at server code when it is a JS error.

Comment: can you show us the serverside code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put the user name in quotes.

```
onclick="postscrape('.$row["instagram_id"].', \''.$row["user_name"].'\', 1);"
```

Answer (score 2):

You didn't quote the user name. The

```
echo 'postscrape('.$row["user_name"].')'
```

yields

```
postscrape(X)
```

...where X is undefined.